# Working with difficult AM/PM formats and REGEX with lubridate in R

Tags: r, regex, datetime, lubridate, data-wrangling

Hello guys I hope everyone is having a good one, I am trying to work with some AM/PM formats in lubridate on R but I cant seem to come up with a proper solution I hope you guys can correct meand help me out please!

I have a HUGE dataset that has date_time formats in a very rare way the format goes as follow:

First a number that represents the day, second an abbreviation of the month OR even the month fully spelled out a 12H time format and the strings " a. m." OR "p. m." or even a combination of more spaces between or missing "dots" then such as "a.  m"  to set an example please take a look at this vector:

```
dates<-c("02 dec 05:47 a. m", 
"7 November 09:47 p. m.",
"3  jul 12:28 a.m.", 
"23 sept 08:53 a m.", 
"7 may 09:05 PM")
```

These make up for more than 95% of the rare formats of datetime in the data set I have been trying to use lubridate on R I am trying to use the function

```
ydm_hm(paste(2021,dates))
```

this is because all dates are form 2021 but I get always:

```
[1] NA                        NA                        NA                       
[4] NA                        "2021-05-07 21:05:00 UTC"
Warning message:
 4 failed to parse.
```

the 4 that fail to parse give me NAS and the only one that parses is correct I do notice that this one has PM or AM as uppercase letters without dots but most of the time my formats will be like this:

```
ydm_hm("7 may 09:05 p.m.")
```

and this gives me NAS...

So I feel as though the only way to get this dates to workout is to change the structure and using REGEX so convert all "a. m." combinations into "AM" and "PM" only after analyzing the data I realized all "p.m" or "a. m." strings come after ONE or TWO spaces after the 12H time format that always have a length of 5 characters and so what should be considered to come up with the patter of the REGEX is the following

the string will begins with one or two numbers then spaces and then letters (for the month abbreviated or fully spelled out after that will have spaces and then 5 characters (that's the 12H time format) and then will have letters spaces and dots for all possible a.m and p.m formats but I have tried with no luck to convert the structure of the date.. if you guys could help me I will be so freaking thankful I dont know if there is a way or another package in R that will even resolve this issue without using regex so thank you everyone for your help !

my desired output will be:

```
"2021-12-02 05;47:00 UTC"
"2021-11-07 09:47:00 UTC"
"2021-07-03 12:28:00 UTC"
"2021-09-23 08:53:00 UTC"
"2021-05-07 21:05:00 UTC"
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your reply I use the code ydm_hm(paste(2021,dates)) because the datetimes filed does not have a year and so I paste the year 2021 into it... because in R I cant seem to find a fun in lubridate to work only with day and month and hour and minutes something like dm_hm() or I tried it with no luck, thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, `parse_date` from `parsedate` works

```
library(parsedate)
parse_date(paste(2021, dates))
```

-output

```
[1] "2021-12-02 05:47:00 UTC"
[2] "2021-11-07 09:47:00 UTC" 
[3] "2021-07-03 12:28:00 UTC"
[4] "2021-09-23 08:53:00 UTC" 
[5] "2021-05-07 21:05:00 UTC"
```

Or if the second value should be `PM`, use `str_remove` to remove the space

```
library(stringr)
parse_date(paste(2021, str_remove_all(dates,
    "(?<=[A-Za-z])[. ]+(?=[A-Za-z])")))
[1] "2021-12-02 05:47:00 UTC" 
[2] "2021-11-07 21:47:00 UTC" 
[3] "2021-07-03 00:28:00 UTC" 
[4] "2021-09-23 08:53:00 UTC" 
[5] "2021-05-07 21:05:00 UTC"
```

---

With `ydm_hm`, the issue is that one of the `am/pm` format showed spaces without the `.` and this may not get parsed.  We could change the format by removing the spaces

```
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
ydm_hm(paste(2021, str_remove_all(dates,
    "(?<=[A-Za-z])[. ]+(?=[A-Za-z])")))
[1] "2021-12-02 05:47:00 UTC" 
[2] "2021-11-07 21:47:00 UTC" 
[3] "2021-07-03 00:28:00 UTC" 
[4] "2021-09-23 08:53:00 UTC" 
[5] "2021-05-07 21:05:00 UTC"
```

Comment: Thank you so much you are one of a kind! thank you for teaching me about this library this worked as I wanted it to thanks a lot from the bottom of my heart!

Comment: This answer doesn't look right to me?

Comment: @langtang I checked with OP's expected output and it is the same

Comment: okay, but I guess I didn't understand why the OP expected a pm time to be 09:47, instead of 21:47. Or an am time to be 12:28 instead of 00:28.  I see that your edited post now has what I would expect to be the correct times

Comment: @langtang if you meant the second element, i was only checking with the OP's desired earlier.  The second solution with `str_remove` gives the pm output

Comment: yes @akrun , and your regex approach is much better than mine, below!!

Comment: @akrun `parsedate` package is ideal for such a task. thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

Since you raised the issue of regular expression, I thought I might try one way to do that

```
library(stringr)

# get boolean for pm dates
pm = str_detect(dates,"(?<=\\d\\d:\\d\\d\\s{1,2})[pP]",)

# convert dates to dates without am/pm
dates = str_extract(dates,"^.*:\\d\\d")

# add pm back to pm dates and am to am dates
dates[pm] <- paste(dates[pm], "PM")
dates[!pm] <- paste(dates[!pm], "AM")

# now your orignal approach works
ydm_hm(paste(2021,dates))
```

Output

```
[1] "2021-12-02 05:47:00 UTC" "2021-11-07 21:47:00 UTC" "2021-07-03 00:28:00 UTC" "2021-09-23 08:53:00 UTC"
[5] "2021-05-07 21:05:00 UTC"
```

Comment: Hey! This is AWESOME thank you for taking the time to teach me this regex formula I WILL BE MOST definitely try it out I feel like it will help me a long the way thanks again, what resources do you recommend to learn regex like a pro just like you?